# Two DELETE statements in Oracle to delete duplicates

Tags: sql, database, oracle, drop-duplicates

We have a table with over 55k rows that have an identifying name duplicated. The name can vary and the number of duplicates with each name can vary. So I applied these 2 scripts for practice deleting duplicate records from a table. Is there a difference? Are there any issues with the scripts? The output seemed the same.

```
DELETE FROM RDSUSER.A_JOB 
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID 
                FROM (SELECT ROWID
                     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JOB_NAME ORDER BY JOB_NAME) DUP 
                      FROM RDSUSER.A_JOB) 
                WHERE DUP > 1);

DELETE FROM RDSUSER.A_JOB JOB
WHERE ROWID > (SELECT MIN(ROWID) 
               FROM A_JOB
               WHERE JOB.JOB_NAME = A_JOB.JOB_NAME);
```

Comment: why not have a test databse and run it yourself

Comment: @nbk This is not so much a request for a fix or solution. This is more so a request for further insight and possible nuances.

Comment: You can run an EXPLAIN aNALYSE and see where the difference is

Comment: They both will produce the same result but I think the second statement will run faster than first one.

Comment: @nbk Just the trick I think I need. Thank you for that.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Thank you as well

Comment: 55K rows is nothing.  Unless you are running this constantly, I doubt it will matter much

Comment: @AnkitBajpai That is incorrect, they do not necessarily produce the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a difference?

Yes.

```sql
DELETE FROM RDSUSER.A_JOB 
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID 
                FROM (SELECT ROWID
                     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JOB_NAME ORDER BY JOB_NAME) DUP 
                      FROM RDSUSER.A_JOB) 
                WHERE DUP > 1);
```

Will `PARTITION BY JOB_NAME` and then `ORDER BY JOB_NAME` and since all the `JOB_NAME` within the partition are going to be identical then the `ORDER BY` clause is non-deterministic and the rows within the partition will be given an effectively random numbering for the rows and it is not guaranteed which rows in the partition will be kept/deleted.

This means that if you run the query and then `ROLLBACK` and run the query again then the set of deleted rows may be different the second time (for example, if you run the query on a parallel system).

```sql
DELETE FROM RDSUSER.A_JOB JOB
WHERE ROWID > (SELECT MIN(ROWID) 
               FROM A_JOB
               WHERE JOB.JOB_NAME = A_JOB.JOB_NAME);
```

Will always keep the minimum `ROWID` for each `JOB_NAME` and the selection of rows to be kept/deleted will be deterministic.

This means that if you run the query and then `ROLLBACK` the change and run the delete a second time then an identical set of rows will be deleted.

---

If you want the queries to function identically then you can use:

```sql
DELETE FROM RDSUSER.A_JOB 
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID 
                FROM (
                  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JOB_NAME ORDER BY ROWID)
                           AS DUP 
                  FROM   RDSUSER.A_JOB
                ) 
                WHERE DUP > 1);
```

---

An example of the random ordering is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a_job (
  id       NUMBER(5,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  job_name VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO a_job (job_name)
SELECT 'a' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'c' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

INSERT INTO a_job (job_name)
SELECT 'a' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

Then after:

```sql
DELETE FROM /*RDSUSER.*/A_JOB 
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ROWID 
                FROM (SELECT ROWID
                     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JOB_NAME ORDER BY JOB_NAME) DUP 
                      FROM /*RDSUSER.*/A_JOB) 
                WHERE DUP > 1);
```

The table may contain:

> | ID | JOB_NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 4 | b |
> | 10 | c |
> | 12 | a |

But if you `ROLLBACK` and then:

```sql
DELETE FROM /*RDSUSER.*/A_JOB JOB
WHERE ROWID > (SELECT MIN(ROWID) 
               FROM A_JOB
               WHERE JOB.JOB_NAME = A_JOB.JOB_NAME);
```

Then the output may be:

> | ID | JOB_NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | a |
> | 4 | b |
> | 6 | c |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=801b834b21ef68949b8b032447b5e3f4)*

Comment: Regardless of ROWID, Both queries will keep only 1 row of 1 JOB_NAME.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai That is true; however, it does not mean that they both keep the **SAME** row and if there is any other unique data in the row then you will see the difference (and I've added an example that shows it). And in the first query it will not necessarily be consistent if you run the query multiple times (if for example row movement is enabled and a row moves and the `ROWID` changes).